# ORA-01017 During APEX ORDS installation

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-rest-data-services

I'm trying to install oracle ORDS on tomcat following this document:

https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-rest-data-services-ords-installation-on-tomcat

When I start this script `$ $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -jar ords.war`

I got ORA-01017 and prompt to enter administrator name.

"Enter the administrator username:"

Then I type sys and sys password but I got same error

Comment: If it's asking for the administrator username, I would expect to enter `admin`. You already provided the sys username/password in your parameters file.

Comment: Please show us a screenshot of the error message with the prompt.

Comment: You might get more response at dba.stackexchange.com.  (But might not.)

Answer (score 0):

The admin user should be a normal DBA user, not sys, which requires "as sysdba" qualifier to connect over a network connection.

Comment: What's a "normal DBA user"?

Comment: I meant a user with the DBA role, not SYSDBA privileges. That said, I'm not sure this entire method is supported; it doesn't match up with Oracle documentation as far as I can tell, or my 20 years past experience with the products.

Answer (score 0):

I've not seen the install method you linked to before. I would advise going with the method described in the actual Oracle documentation, which does not include doing anything with the ords_params.properties file directly.

Check this link: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-rest-data-services/19.2/aelig/installing-REST-data-services.html#GUID-6F7B4E61-B730-4E73-80B8-F53299123730

Or the ORDS install section of this document: https://pmdba.files.wordpress.com/2019/09/ha-oracle-ords-apex-with-http-header-authentication.pdf